# Adding rows to a table changes the width?

Tags: html, css, html-table

When I'm adding `tr` rows to an existing `tbody`, the table's width "magically" changes - why is that so / how to prevent that?

My HTML:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-sm" style="width: 50%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Info</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="list">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This table resides within a Bootstrap Grid column (within a fluid container, if that matters). In the beginning the table fills 50% of the width of the grid column, after adding rows via JavaScript the table's width changes and even outgrows the grid resulting in a bad design.

Comment: what is the added row's content? Can you post the javascript, please?

Answer (score 0):

Add this class to your table

```
.is-breakable {
    word-break: break-word;
}
```